# Send an image with axios and formidable ( nodejs -> express )

Tags: node.js, express, axios, formidable

i'm trying to send an image with axios (nodejs) to express server with formidable.
This is the code of axios script:

```
const axios = require('axios');
const fs = require('fs')
const FormData = require('form-data')

var img = fs.readFileSync("C:/Users/alessio/Documents/FX/screenshot.png", 'utf8'); 
console.log(img)
let data = new FormData();
data.append('img', img, "img.png")
console.log(data);
axios.post('http://192.168.43.193:3000/testAPI/upload_img_mt', data, {
    headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en,q=0.8',
        'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data; boundary=${data._boundary}`,
        'timeout': 999999
    },
})
    .then(function (response){
        //console.log(response);
    })
```

And this is the code serverside with express and the response managed with formidable:

```
router.post('/upload_img_mt', function(req, res, next){
    console.log(req)

    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.uploadDir = "fxdiary";
    form.encoding = 'utf8';
    form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file){
        console.log(form.uploadDir + "/" + file.name);
    });
    form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
        console.log(files);
        console.log(err);
        console.log(fields);
    });
    res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

The file image is saved but is not correct png image. The size of the image is not correct and change sometimes randomly. Ad example the original file size is 33k and become 900bytes or 54k or another value.

Whats happen? Where is the problem in this code?

Comment: could you comment  console.log(files);
        console.log(err);
        console.log(fields);
the debug log for these three

Comment: the log in callback of parse are not printed in console.. the only log printed is at the 'fileBegin'.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass boundary in Content-type header as it's auto added by browser. you might breaking default boundary mechanism.

If you still face file size issue then try with [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#readme) module for file handling on Nodejs side

Comment: The nodejs script is runned without browser and if i remove the boundary the result is: Error: bad content-type header, no multipart boundary

Comment: with multer not work.. the error is _MulterError: Unexpected field_ in the response ( error 500 )

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u-NgejAL_gWytB1wpQ-yPjHbWeMdawgE/view

Comment: The name of appended data to form must be the same handled by upload.single('name'). The second part of solution is the encoding sended by axios: must be the same of multer ( 7bit ). The fs.readFileSync without encoding specified done the rest.

Comment: Yeah. i meant the same way when i mentioned multer.